# counting neighbors method in game of life

Tags: java, javafx, conways-game-of-life

I know that it was many questions about game of life, but still I can't understand how to write this method correctly in javafx.
here is my code which doesn't work, because I don't understand how to implement algorithm for counting neighbors.

```
public void stepMethod(ActionEvent event){
    for (int x = 0; x < cellSize; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < cellSize; y++){
            int neighbours = countNeighbors(x, y);
            nextGeneration[x][y] = board [x][y];
            nextGeneration[x][y] = (neighbours == 3) ? true: nextGeneration[x][y];
            nextGeneration[x][y] = ((neighbours < 2) || (neighbours > 3)) ? false : nextGeneration[x][y];
        }
    }
    draw();
}

public int countNeighbors(int x, int y){
    int neighbours = 0;
    if (board [x-1][y-1]){
        neighbours+=1;
    }else{
        neighbours+=0;
    }
    if (board[x][y-1]){
        neighbours+=1;
    }else{
        neighbours+=0;
    }
    if (board[x+1][y-1]){
        neighbours+=1;
    }else{
        neighbours+=0;
    }
    if (board[x-1][y]){
        neighbours+=1;
    }else{
        neighbours+=0;
    }
    if (board[x+1][y]){
        neighbours+=1;
    }else{
        neighbours+=0;
    }
    if (board[x-1][y+1]){
        neighbours+=1;
    }else{
        neighbours+=0;
    }
    if (board[x][y+1]){
        neighbours+=1;
    }else{
        neighbours+=0;
    }
    if (board[x+1][y+1]){
        neighbours+=1;
    }else{
        neighbours+=0;
    }
    if(board[x][y]){
        neighbours--;
    }
    return neighbours;
}
```

and here is my draw method

```
public void draw(){
    initGraphics();
    for(int x = 0; x < cellSize; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < cellSize; y++){
            if(board[x][y] ){
                gc.setFill(Color.CHOCOLATE);
                gc.fillOval(x*cellSize,y*cellSize,cellSize,cellSize);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I presume `x-1` or `x+1` could go off the edge (same for `y`). What actually goes wrong?

Comment: it doesn't work, when I press this step method, and I have mistakes during compilation, but I don't know what exactly is wrong

Comment: Share the error messages from compilation then :-)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at sample.Controller.countNeighbors(Controller.java:54)
 at sample.Controller.stepMethod(Controller.java:118)

Comment: By "share the error messages" it was intended that you [edit] your question and include the entire error message. Have you [read the error message and tried to understand it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/2775450)? (BTW, that is not a compilation error: if you had compilation errors you wouldn't have been able to run the application.)

Comment: sorry, it's my first year of studies and I don't have any experience in this

Comment: @Ira That's why I provided a link for you to learn how to do it.

Comment: BTW: Some of the code can be shortened: `nextGeneration[x][y] = (neighbors == 3);` in the body of the for loop in `stepMethod`. Furthermore all `else{
        neighbours+=0;
    }` can be removed, those statements do not have any effect. Also to count the values you could simply use a loop and subtract the value for the "center" again: `int neighbors = (neighbors[x][y] ? -1 : 0); for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) { for (int j=-1; j <= 1; j++) { if (board[x+i][y+j]) { neighbors++;}}}`

Comment: Sorry, the part for the loop should be `nextGeneration[x][y] = (neighbors == 3 || ((neighbors == 2) && board[x][y]));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at
 sample.Controller.countNeighbors(Controller.java:54) at
 sample.Controller.stepMethod(Controller.java:118)
```

is a runtime error - not compilation error. It says you index (i.e. stuff from `[x-1]` etc) has gone `OutOfBounds`.

You need to add even more conditions in the ifs and elses, for example

```
if (board [x-1][y-1]){
```

will be a problem is `x` or `y` is 0, so

```
if (x>0 && y>0 && board [x-1][y-1]){
```

You need to check against the upper bound too further down.

Decide what to do at the edges of the board. Wrap round? Make itthe edge of the world? Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

At your first iteration you'll have `x=0 and y=0`. So evaluating `board[x-1][y-1]` will give you a board[-1][-1] which will raise the `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.